# How can I change the Value in HSV color via scripting?

Tags: c#, unity

I have a glowing object (point light attached to a ball with a default shader with the emission property) in my scene and I've added a script to make the point light flicker.

The script randomly changes the intensity of the point light to make it flicker.

Since I'm using an emission shader, the ball can also be seen without light.

I'm using HDR values in my emission shader and by changing the Value in the HSV Color picker I can change the color of the ball to black.

I need help in linking the value of the HSV color on the emission shader of the ball to the intensity of the point light.

Any help would be useful! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
material.SetColor ("_Color", myColor)
```

or

```
material.SetColor ("_TintColor", myColor);
```

That changes the values directly on the shader material. I hope that helps!

Comment: It does but I need to change the V of the HSV without changing the Hue or Saturation.
Thanks though!

Comment: Have you tried setting the alpha for the second parameter?
Ex: `material.SetColor("_Color", new Color(0.5f, 0.6f, 0.7f,0.8f));` @user3927312

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
Color newColor = Color.HSVToRGB(h, s, v, true); // "true" indicates to allow HDR values

material.Setcolor("_EmissionColor", newColor);
```